# Does lovell sharp support color modulation (hue, saturation, brightness)?

Tags: node.js, sharp

I have application where I need to change colors of image by altering values of hue, saturation and lightness.

Following is the sample image:

[image]

When I will pass HSL value as 90, 100, 50 respectively.

It should return image as follows

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this in node sharp?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please check this issue https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered here:

https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips/issues/770

Summary: at the command-line you can do:

```
$ vips colourspace red-shirt.jpg x.v lch
$ vips linear x.v green-shirt.jpg "1.5 1.5 1" "0 0 120"
```

to swap to LCh colourspace and adjust hue and chroma, or in [node-vips](https://github.com/jcupitt/node-vips) you can do:

```
var vips = require('vips');

var image = vips.Image.newFromFile(process.argv[2]);
image = image
    .colourspace('lch')
    .add([0, 0, 120])
    .multiply([1.5, 1.5, 1]);
image.writeToFile(process.argv[3]);
```